# Objective-C Class extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I've started learning obj-C just recently so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. 
I want to access "passCode" (extension) with clpPlayerStats object, but it's impossible to do ("Property not found on object..."). Is there any simple way to fix this?

clpPlayerStats.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface clpPlayerStats : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString* name; 

@end
```

clpPlayerStats.m

```
#import "clpPlayerStats.h"

@interface clpPlayerStats()

    @property (nonatomic) unsigned int passCode;

@end

@implementation clpPlayerStats
@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "clpPlayerStats.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        clpPlayerStats *clapslock = [[clpPlayerStats alloc] init];
        NSString *username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxPussySlayerxxx"];
        clapslock.name = username;
        clapslock.passCode = 12; // <------ "Property not found on object..."
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, class names should always start with second letters.

Secondly, Class Extensions **extend the @interface** of the class.  And, with all things C, whether or not a declaration of anything can be seen is entirely dependent on whether the compiler can see the declaration at the time of use.

So, if you want to declare something that is semi-private, then you would typically move your `@interface ClpPlayerStats()` extension to a Private header file;  `ClpPlayerStats_Private.h`.   Then, if you want to access the "private" API, you `#import ClpPlayerStats_Private.h`.

There really isn't a formal notion of privacy in Objective-C.  Just visibility to the compiler.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that I can achieve the same thing with the class extension as you did with the private header . Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
@interface clpPlayerStats()

    @property (nonatomic) unsigned int passCode;

@end
```

you are declaring a private property. If you want to use `passCode` outside the scope of your class you have to add in the public interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface clpPlayerStats : NSObject

    @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
    @property (nonatomic) unsigned int passCode; 

@end
```

and remove the interface in the `.m`

Comment: I'm currently reading "Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" and the author says that in order to create an extension (identical case) I have to add an @interface to .m and then delete the property form the header. Is there any way to access passCode without adding additional property to .h?

Comment: @BartoszKunat Does the author use the property outside the class with that private interface?

Comment: It isn't an "additional property" you have it in the .h *or* the .m. It is about the scope you want for the property.

Comment: Now I understand the whole concept. Turns out he never actually used it in the main.m- I incorrectly assumed that he did the whole extension thing in the .m to use it exclusively in the main.m with the (in my example) clpPlayerStats objects. Thanks for help!

Comment: That isn't declaring a private property;  it is quite common to use class extensions to break up the interface of a class in the public declaration.   Privacy in Objective-C (save for ivar accessibility) is entirely determined by location of declaration in terms of files and not by the declaration itself.